# redux-saga: Actions must be plain objects

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a problem with my saga and I don't have any idea what is wrong. Im getting an error like Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions while using react redux. Here is my code.

**container/index.js**

```
class AppContainer extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const { actions: { onFetchPhoto } } = this.props;
        onFetchPhoto();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <App />
        );
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    actions: {
        onFetchPhoto: () => dispatch(fetchPhoto())
    }
})


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer);
```

**actions/index.js**

```
export const FETCH_PHOTO_REQUEST = "FETCH_PHOTO_REQUEST";
export const FETCH_PHOTO_SUCCESS = "FETCH_PHOTO_SUCCESS";
export const FETCH_PHOTO_FAILURE = "FETCH_PHOTO_FAILURE";

export function fetchPhoto(payload) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PHOTO_REQUEST
    }
}
export function fetchPhotoSuccess(payload) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PHOTO_SUCCESS,
        payload
    }
}
export function fetchPhotoFailure(error) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PHOTO_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
            error
        }
    }
}
```

**sagas/index.js**

```
function* fetchRandomPhoto() {
    //yield put(fetchPhoto());

    const {
        response,
        error
    } = yield call(fetchRandomPhotoApi)

    if (response) {
        yield put(fetchPhotoSuccess(response))
    } else {
        yield put(fetchPhotoFailure(error))
    }
}

function* watchLoadRandomPhoto() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            yield takeLatest(FETCH_PHOTO_REQUEST, fetchRandomPhoto);
        }
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.error("error in saga", error)
    }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield fork(watchLoadRandomPhoto)
}
```

**services/index.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
    URL,
    PUBLIC_KEY
} from 'src/constants/config';

import {
    schema,
    normalize
} from 'normalizr'

export function fetchRandomPhotoApi() {
    return axios({
            url: `${URL}/photos/random`,
            timeout: 10000,
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Autorization': `Client-ID ${PUBLIC_KEY}`
            },
            responseType: 'json'
        })
        .then((response) => {
            const { data } = response.data;
            console.log("d");
            if (data) {
                return ({
                    response: {
                        id: data.id,
                        url: data.urls.full,
                        title: data.location.title
                    }
                })
            }
        })
       .catch(error => error)
}
```

**store/configureStore.js**

```
import rootReducer from 'src/reducers/root';
import rootSaga from 'src/sagas';


export default function configureStore() {
    const logger = createLogger();
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(
                sagaMiddleware,
                logger,
                composeEnhancers
            ),
        )
    );

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

    return store;
}
```

I waste 2 day to fix this problem, but no result. Chrome showed me this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found my problem, but I don't understand why. I added this code.

**store/index.js**

```
export default function configureStore() {
    const logger = createLogger();
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(
                sagaMiddleware,
                logger
            ),
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : (fn) => fn
        )
    );

    store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;

    return store;
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import configureStore from 'src/store/configureStore';

import Routes from 'src/routes/root';
import rootSaga from 'src/sagas';

const store = configureStore();

store.runSaga(rootSaga);

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
                <Routes store={store} />
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Also this line make my app work.

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : (fn) => fn
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem lies within fetchRandomPhotoApi function. Without knowing what that looks like I can't say for certain but if it is for example a function that return a promise you should be calling like

```
const { response, error } = yield call(fetchRandomPhotoApi)
```

Notice the lack of brackets in the call.

### Update

From your edit I can now see that the promise is not resolved in your api call. You want that function to return an object instead of the actual promise to pass on to your actions. Something on the lines of:

```
axios({...etc}).then(response => response).catch(error => error)
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it returns promise. But still not working, I added configureStore and api. I think this problem happening when react try to start a function in componentDidMount and say that it is not plain object, but i use dispatch

Comment: From your edit it looks like you might have to process your axios promise. I don't use axios so I'm not that sure but don't you need to chain a .then() to resolve a promise into an object?

Comment: yes, I need .then() and i fixed it. But this method fetchRandomPhotoApi doesn't execute (I checked in console). I think it is because of error before calling Api method